# Which one should I use "this" or "gameObject" when accessing the GameObject to which the derived class of MonoBehaviour is attached?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am learning Unity3D from zero. I found that we can access the `GameObject` to which a script declaring a derived class of `MonoBehaviour` is attached as follows.

- via `this`
- via `gameObject`
- via private field with `[SerializedField]` attribute.

## Trivial Code

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Ball : MonoBehaviour
{

    [SerializeField]
    private GameObject ball;

    void Update()
    {
        Vector3 force = new Vector3
        {
            x = 5 * Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"),
            y = 0,
            z = 5 * Input.GetAxis("Vertical")
        };

        //gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(force);
        //this.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(force);
        ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>().AddForce(force);
    }
}
```

## Question

Among those three, I only want to know when we need to choose `this` instead of `gameObject` and also the reverse?

Comment: You should not be calling GetComponent in Update. That's very bad for performance. You should caching the rigidbody instead.

Comment: `this` referes to the instance of "this class" (the one you write this in) with `gameObject` you refer to the gameObject your MonoBehaviour (aka component) is attached to. `[SerializedField]` lets you expose a private field to the inspector (unity editor gui). those 3 things are fundamentally different

Comment: @yes, then the question is: which should I use to access a component because both `this` and `gameObject` can call `GetComponent`?

Comment: `(this.)GetComponent` is the same as `(this.)gameObject.GetComponent`. Same for example with `(this.)transfrom` does the same as `(this.)gameObject.transform`. just "syntactic sugar". you only need to specify the gameObject if its not the one the component is attached to (or you can also call it on components attached to other gameobjects, which then means otherGameobject.GetComponent)

Comment: @yes: I still don't understand your statement "you only need to specify the gameObject if its not the one the component is attached to (or you can also call it on components attached to other gameobjects, which then means otherGameobject.GetComponent)" .


IMHO, a script is always attached to a game object. If I call `transform` or `GetComponent` via either `this` or `this.gameObject`, it is clear that I refer to the `transform` or `GetComponent` that belong to the game object to which the script is attached. So I still don't understand when I have to explicitly mention `gameObject`?

Comment: When you want to use properties or methods `GameObject` implements (and there is no "wrapper" like for example `Component.GetComponent<T>` or `Component.transform`). Or when you need a reference to gameObject in specific, like for example `Destroy(this)` would only destroy the Component/Script you called it from, while `Destroy(gameObject)` would get rid of the whole gameObject.

Comment: Also what I meant with "or you can also call it on components attached to other gameobjects, which then means otherGameobject.GetComponent" is that - for example - `FindObjectOfType<MySpecialScript>().GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` would result in the same as `FindObjectOfType<MySpecialScript>().gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>()` would (ignore whether its a good example) Its because both `GameObject` and `Component` (which MonoBehaviour derives from) implement `GetComponent` and one is just a "convenience-wrapper" for the other.

Comment: @yes: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are different things!

When you are using `this`, you are referencing the [This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/this) keyword, which in this case is talking about the `MonoBehaviour` you are writing.

When you use `gameObject`, you are talking about the `gameobject` that the behaviour you are writing is contained. This `gameObject` can contain othe `MonoBehaviours`.

So for example, if your `MonoBehaviour` has an property you can reference it with "this". And if the `gameobject` has a Physics Component, you can use `GetComponent` to access it.